# Prometheus: how to stop alerting on a dead system

Tags: prometheus

I've got my backup server reporting the age of the last successful backup to Prometheus, and I alert when that gets too old. I've just permanently shut down a server, and of course Prometheus is now alerting.

What's the correct way to deal with this? I could modify the alert such that it ignores that server, but I'm thinking that there's probably a better way to deal with this situation.